# Controlling a spawned Thread from multiple activities in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, object-reference

I have an application that runs a background thread which periodically performs a task. The UI thread moves through several different activities.

The tutorial I used can be found at [this blog](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/), the gist of it is the following:

- Create a class that extends Thread

`public final class JSONThread extends Thread {`

- Define a method in this class that adds a task to the MessageQueue, prompting executing when able.

`public synchronized void enqueueJSON(final JSON.JSON task) {`

However, after creating the initial object in my main activity, navigating to another activity obviously loses the Object bound to my Thread. I am no longer able to call methods on that Object (hence unable to add to queue).

I am unsure if this is caused by a wrong decision in architecture on my part or by overseeing the obvious solution. Any ideas? Note that I am trying to avoid AsyncTask for this purpose, since a pool of five threads for a simple task seems a little too much.

Comment: Your thread, while still needing to be a thread, should be implemented within a Service which can have multiple Activities as clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store a Thread object as member of some other object with lifetime longer than Activity.

Two ideas for you:

a) It could be a member of Application (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

You may have problems with this, if you don't have a Service running. There is no guarantee that your application won't be killed (as example if any system dialog will pop up on top of your activities)

b) It could be a member of Service 
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a service, not a thread.  A service will remain in the background so long as there is an activity bound to it, and it won't be reset when an activity exits.

Comment: If only I could mark two answers; sorry about that. Using a service is indeed the answer to the problem.